# Keep part of string after hyphen for specific column

Tags: unix, awk, sed, cut

For column 2 in my input files I want to keep the part after the hyphen. I have tried a `cut` command, but don't know how to apply this to the second column only:

```
echo TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT   1-230823 | cut -d - -f 2
230823
```

Input:

```
TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT   1-230823
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC    2-172580
```

Out:

```
TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT   230823
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC    172580
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:space:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[0-9]+-/\1/' file
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/vLr98F):

```
s='TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT   1-230823
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC    2-172580'
sed -E 's/^([^[:space:]]+[[:blank:]]+)[0-9]+-/\1/' <<< "$s"
# TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT   230823
# GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC    172580
```

The POSIX ERE (`-E` option enables this syntax) regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `([^[:space:]]+[[:blank:]]+)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value): one or more non-whitespace chars followed with one or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `[0-9]+-` - 1 or more digits and a `-`.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you in `awk`. Simply substitute everything till `-` in 2nd column and then print the line(written and tested with shown samples).

```
awk '{sub(/.*-/,"",$2)} 1' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to mention field number into an `awk` variable;e then try:

```
awk -v field="2" '{sub(/.*-/,"",$field)} 1' Input_file
```

***Generic solution(which handles multiple field values):*** In case OP needs to perform substitution in multiple fields which can be defined into an `awk` variable then please try following.

```
awk -v field="2,3" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(field,array,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){ fields[array[i]] }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i in fields){ sub(/.*-/,"",$i) }
  }
}
1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this awk:

```
awk '{sub(/^[^-]*-/, "", $2)} 1' file
```

```
TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT 230823
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC 172580
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]*-//' file
TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT   230823
```

Answer (score 1):

And with the `FS` variable, another solution with `awk` can be:

`awk -v FS='[0-9]+-' '{print $1 $2}'  input`

```
TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT   230823
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC    172580
```

Answer (score 0):

With multiple delimiters, i.e. hyphen and space, it is better to use `awk`, e.g.:

```
<infile awk '{ print $1, $3 }' FS='[- ]+'
```

Output:

```
TCCCATATGGTCTAGCGGTTAGGATTCCT 230823
GCATTGGTGGTTCAGTGGTAGAATTCTC 172580
```